# Setup a Windows 7 machine to act as Server while connected to same Wifi

Tags: sql-server, networking, windows-7

I have two laptops one running Windows 8.1 and other running Windows 7. Both are connected to the same wifi router. I want to bring them on the same network because I want the Windows 7 machine to act as a Server so that I can host my SQL Server database on it.

Which means Windows 7 machine name should appear in list of 'Server Name' combo of SQL Server connection properties dialog box.

Comment: Can be closed under the official close reason: _Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are connected to same router means they already are on a same network.

Assign unique IP to your laptops from router settings (Typically hosted at http://192.168.0.1/).

Do the ping test from cmd.

Enable TCP/IP Protocol for SQL Server.

You should now be able to connect SQL from remote machine with it's IP.